# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a navbar which when clicked will affect the display of other elements (none / visible), For the list the background can appear according to the code but for code that affects generic, statistics, and about classes an error appears as in the title, please help. 
sorry if the english is bad

```js
let generic = document.querySelector(".generic");
let statistics = document.querySelector(".statistics");
let about = document.querySelector(".aboutMe");
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

let parentlist = document.getElementById("parent-list");

// locate your element and add the Click Event Listener
parentlist.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

    const target = e.target;
            

    // e.target is our targetted element.
    if(target.id == "genericnav") {
        target.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
        generic.style.display = "visible";
        statistics.style.display = "none";
        about.style.display = "none";
    }

    else if(target.id == "statisticsnav") {
        target.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
        generic.style.display = "none";
        statistics.style.display = "visible";
        about.style.display = "none";
    }

    else if(target.id == "aboutnav") {
        target.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
        generic.style.display = "none";
        statistics.style.display = "none";
        about.style.display = "visible";
    }
            
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: 28px;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    line-height: 70px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    line-height: 450%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dark-mode {
    flex-basis: 33%;
    line-height: 450%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 21px;
    transform: translateY(25px);
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

.generic {
  display: visible;
}

.statistics {
  display: none;
}

.aboutMe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Covid-19</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            Covid-19
        </div>
         
        <ul id="parent-list">
            <li id="genericnav">Generic</li>
            <li id="statisticsnav">Statistics</li>
            <li id="aboutnav">About Me</li>
        </ul>
        

        <div class="dark-mode">Night
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main">



        <div class="generic">
            <p>generic</p>
        </div>


        <div class="statistics">
          <p>statistics</p>
        </div>


        <div class="aboutMe">
          <p>about</p>        
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a `<generic>` tag, so `document.querySelector("generic")` will return `null`. Use the `.generic` selector to find an element with the _class_ `generic`. The same applies for `statistics`. There don't seem to be any element with the tag or class `about`, so I'm not sure what you would expect there.

Comment: ah yeah my bad, thanks for answering and giving reference, its very helpful!